# In-place initialization of structs in std container

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, std

```
struct vertex
{
     th::Vector3 point[2];
     std::list<vertex>::iterator pointConnection[2];
};

std::list<vertex> vertices;
vertices.push_back(
     {{vertex1->_getDerivedPosition(), vertex2->_getDerivedPosition()},
     {vertices.end(), vertices.end()}}
);
```

I couldn't find a reason why this won't work whilst the following compiles fine? Can you explain please? What am I doing wrong?

```
vertex v = {{vertex1->_getDerivedPosition(), vertex2->_getDerivedPosition()},
     {vertices.end(), vertices.end()};
```

Comment: `vertex` is not a POD type, because it's members aren't POD types

Comment: @TonyTheLion I have edited the question. I forgot about that vector3 and iterator there. The struct was very different when I was preparing the question. Have been trying different things prior to asking.

Comment: Still, if the second one works, isn't putting that in push_back supposed to work? I have been having problems with this subject for a long time now, I can never get it right the first time.
Do I need a constructor and use emplace if its not POD? Will constructor have a lot of performance penalty because this will be done A LOT.

Comment: Visual C++ doesn't support list-initialization, simple as that. Your `vertex v = { ... };` line is aggregate initialization.

Comment: @Xeo Thanks, that explains. Just googled that 2012 CTP supports that so it will be supported the next version I hope. I am going with constructor and emplace for now then.

Comment: When something like this doesn't work, try something simpler, e.g. `std::list<int> l{ 1, 2, 3 }`, if that still doesn't work it's a lot easier to figure out if you're doing something wrong or if it's a limitation of your compiler and/or stdlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no way in MSVC to do this, yet.